# Second devise model not using generated views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a User and a Rep model

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'user_registration'}
devise_for :reps
```

I ran

```
rails generate devise:views reps
```

The custom views show up in app/views/reps

But the rep paths are still using the built in devise views

Rendered ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.4.9/app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

Instead of the generated reps views.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By simply putting the views there Devise won't use them. You would need to point `Devise::RegistrationsController` to the right controller which has these views, which you can  do by calling this:

```
 devise_for :reps, :controllers => { :registrations => "reps/registrations" }
```

This needs to have a new controller defined at `app/controllers/reps/registrations_controller.rb`:

```
 class Reps::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

 end
```

You would then have the views in the right directory for this controller to use.

Comment: Hmm, seems weird that you would have to create these "pass-through" controllers for each devise controller just to use the proper views for a second devise model.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem.  I eventually spotted this in the documentation.

> If you have more than one role in your application (such as “User” and “Admin”), you will notice that Devise uses the same views for all roles. Fortunately, Devise offers an easy way to customize views. All you need to do is set “config.scoped_views = true” inside “config/initializers/devise.rb”.

So I switched the config.scoped_views to true and it worked a charm :)

Comment: This is actually the better answer.

Comment: I made the mistake of only uncommenting that line in the initializer - forgot to actually change it to `true`

Comment: ahhh! I missed the `s` in `rails g devise:views admins`.

Comment: I'd like to point out that in rails 5 I had to restart the server for changes to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem and I realized that the model names are case sensitive.  I used the command

```
rails generate devise:views Admins
```

Instead of

```
rails generate devise:views admins
```

and it created the folder at '/app/views/Admins' but was looking for the custom view in 'app/views/admins'