# setting Devise after_sign_in_path_for with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have some basic experience with Devise in a previous application that had only one Devise model.  However, I am rewriting it all from scratch to have expanded functionality, and in the second iteration I think it best to have two separate user models (patient_user and staff_user).

I am aware of CanCan and Rolify, and will be using those for one of the models but not the other.

My problem is with setting the after_sign_in_path_for and redirecting each model to a different "home screen".

I have set each model to a separate after_sign_up_path and that works beautifully.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  # Creating separate after_sign_up_paths for patient_user and staff_user

  def after_sign_up_path_for(patient_user)
    flash[:notice] = 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
    privacy_agreement_path
  end

  # Add an after_sign_up path for staff_user
  def after_sign_up_path_for(staff_user)
    flash[:notice] = 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'
    dashboard_path
  end

end
```

Apparently after_sign_in_path_for should be defined in Application Controller though rather than in Sessions Controller.

[Stack Overflow question clarifying this difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451881/devise-after-sign-in-path-for-works-but-not-the-other-ones)

Here's my best attempt:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case resource
    when patient_user
      privacy_agreement_path  
    when staff_user
      dashboard_path
    end
  end

end
```

which gives error:

```
undefined local variable or method `patient_user' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x00000109a40e48>
```

If I capitalise the case select conditions then it seems to recognise the variable but I get a completely different error:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    case resource
    when Patient_user
      privacy_agreement_path  
    when Staff_user
      dashboard_path
    end
  end

end
```

which gives error

```
  Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Patient_user (RuntimeError)
  ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11:in `after_sign_in_path_for'
```

I have tried a lot of Googling and looked at various other Devise and Circular Dependency problems but have not been able to find a work around, I guess I'm not good enough at Devise to know what I'm doing.

The one other thing I tried was making patient_user and staff_user separate after_sign_in_path_for calls in Application controller

```
#application_controller.rb
  def after_sign_in_path_for(patient_user)
     privacy_agreement_path  
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(staff_user)
     dashboard_path  
  end
```

This works for staff_user, but going to /patient_users/sign_in and giving a valid username and password instead redirects to dashboard_path (not privacy_agreement_path).

The problem seems to be focussed around the use of "resource" and the conditional statement that is intended to redirect "patient_user" accounts to "privacy_agreement_path" and "staff_user" accounts to "dashboard_path".  This works well for after_sign_up_path in RegistrationsController, but not in after_sign_in_path in ApplicationController.

Other files

```
#routes.rb
devise_for :patient_users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }
devise_for :staff_users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }
```

——

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320398/second-devise-model-not-using-generated-views
  # Workaround for having multiple Devise models, used the second answer
  config.scoped_views = true
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I tried Vapire's solution:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # check for the class of the object to determine what type it is
    case resource.class
    when PatientUser
      privacy_agreement_path  
    when StaffUser
      dashboard_path
    end
  end
end
```

but this started up the error:

```
      undefined method `staff_user_url' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x000001047a0198> (NoMethodError)
```

With a bit of Googling I found [this discussion on Devise github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1350), with a total lack of consensus on whether this is some kind of bug or just a poor implementation.

I followed the suggested solution though, which was to update routes.rb

```
#routes.rb
  devise_for :patient_users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }
  devise_for :staff_users, :controllers => { :registrations => :registrations }

  resources :patient_users #added as bugfix
  resources :staff_users #added as bug fix
```

This gave a new error:

```
      uninitialized constant StaffUsersController (ActionController::RoutingError)
```

So I created a new Controller file:

```
#controllers/staff_users_controller.rb
class StaffUsersController < ApplicationController

end
```

which gave error

```
  The action 'show' could not be found for StaffUsersController (AbstractController::ActionNotFound)
```

So I added that to the controller file

```
#controllers/staff_users_controller.rb
class StaffUsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
  end

end
```

Of course that prompted this error:

```
  Missing template staff_users/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
```

So I added that file too (just a blank file at `app/views/staff_users.html.erb`)

which then works, but redirects to the wrong page `/staff_users/1`

So I modified the controller again

```
#controllers/staff_users_controller.rb
class StaffUsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    redirect_to dashboard_path
  end

end
```

And then everything works.  This seems like an enormously overcomplicated solution though, had to do the same thing for PatientUsers, and I've picked up a lot of spare resource routes that I don't need either.

**EDIT 2:**

Debugger information as requested by Mandeep.

```
[7, 16] in /Users/Me/Code/medapp/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   7    # https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out
   8    # redirect successfully signed in users to the dashboard
   9    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   10      debugger
   11      # check for the class of the object to determine what type it is
=> 12      case resource.class
   13      when PatientUser
   14        privacy_agreement_path  
   15      when StaffUser
   16        dashboard_path
(rdb:2) resource.show
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `show' for #<PatientUser:0x0000010171c1c0>

(rdb:2) @resource = resource
#<PatientUser id: 2, email: "patient_user@example.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$qY0jBEC8UZHD883ryq69BevPo5oxV.9LPDM8K44gXqcD...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 16, current_sign_in_at: "2014-07-03 08:46:07", last_sign_in_at: "2014-07-03 08:45:06", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2014-07-03 03:05:01", updated_at: "2014-07-03 08:46:07">
```

Seems exactly as expected to me, should indicate that resource.class would work fine without any huge workarounds, but obviously not.

**Solution**

So just using an If conditional instead of a case conditional fixed the whole thing, no need for any of that other stuff.  I have no idea why this is, but it's an adequate solution.

```
#registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  # BUGFIX
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451881/devise-after-sign-in-path-for-works-but-not-the-other-ones
  # Creating separate after_sign_up_paths for patient_user and staff_user
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    # check for the class of the object to determine what type it is
    if resource.class == PatientUser
      privacy_agreement_path
    elsif resource.class == StaffUser
      dashboard_path
    end 
  end

end
```

AND

```
#application_controllers.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # check for the class of the object to determine what type it is
    if resource.class == PatientUser
      privacy_agreement_path
    elsif resource.class == StaffUser
      dashboard_path
    end 
  end

end
```

Thanks to Mandeep and Vapire for their help!!

Comment: can you use a debugger and check what resource values are you getting in your after_sign_in_path_for method?

Comment: How do I do that?  I'm still somewhat new to Rails, and just wrapping my head around building a whole Cucumber/RSpec test suite for my app.  I thought it might be a good idea to find out what is in resources as well but didn't know how to do it, I guess something using the rails console maybe but I don't have much experience with that either.

Comment: check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debugger-gem

Comment: check what does resource gives to you in terminal and then its class as @Vapire has suggested and based on the result you can use if else statement to redirect your users

Comment: Solved, thank you very much.  Not sure why, but it works, that's good enough for today.

Comment: @user2792268 I wonder if you had one single login form for the two separate models and how you do it if that was the case. Im trying to implement one SessionsController to do the login, but having problems creating a single form that works for two models.

Comment: @JosEduSol I have two separate login forms so I doubt I can be of much help. My untested suggestion is to associate the form to one model by default, and then on form submission check which model it should belong to and then if necessary pass the parameters over to a separate controller action for the other model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that your both user models are called `PatientUser` and `StaffUser` You should do this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    # check for the class of the object to determine what type it is
    case resource.class
    when PatientUser
      privacy_agreement_path  
    when StaffUser
      dashboard_path
    end
  end
end
```

To elaborate a bit on your other tries:

After Devise has signed in the user for you it simply makes one call of `after_sign_in_path(resource)` to your application controller. Whether it invokes the standard implementation provided by Devise itself or a custom implementation is a non-issue for Devise. It leaves the distinction of what to do fully to you if you implement it yourself. Hence it's your responsibility to check what type is coming as the resource param if you want to react to it.

```
# application_controller.rb

# you implement the method once
def after_sign_in_path_for(patient_user)
  privacy_agreement_path  
end

# you implement it twice which means
# this overrides the above method, so a call to after_sign_in_path will always
# result in calling this method, no matter what type of user it is
def after_sign_in_path_for(staff_user)
  dashboard_path  
end
```

Just because you name your parameter a certain way it doesn't give information on what type of parameter it is. That's not how OO programming is designed.

Comment: Doh, I should have known that renaming the resource parameter does nothing.  Your solution kind-of worked.  see updates in post.

Comment: Fixed, see edits/comments in OP.  Thanks for your help @Vapire.